# How fix Error: Unexpected null value flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart

how solve this .
in moblie phone it works prefectly but when i build in web i have this error
Some helps please !

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:60879/cssBXX81wfI=
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
Token: null
====> API Call: /api/v1/config
Header: {Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, zoneId: null, X-localization: fr, Authorization: Bearer null}
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:5405:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:5732:30)
    at [_configureOverlay] (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:3027:53)
    at [_show] (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:3190:30)
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:5609:16)
    at Object.callMethod (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:5652:17)
    at Object.dsend (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:5655:17)
    at get_queue.GetQueue.new._check$ (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart.lib.js:91:65)
    at _check$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43083:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43114:7)
    at [_check] (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart.lib.js:86:20)
    at get_queue.GetQueue.new.add (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart.lib.js:79:19)
    at snackbar_controller._SnackBarQueue.new._addJob (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:3325:40)
    at _addJob.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43083:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43114:7)
    at [_addJob] (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:3323:20)
    at snackbar_controller.SnackbarController.new.show (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:2996:76)
    at Object.ExtensionSnackbar$124showSnackbar [as ExtensionSnackbar|showSnackbar]
    (http://localhost:60787/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:12329:16)
    at Object.showCustomSnackBar (http://localhost:60787/packages/efood_multivendor/view/base/custom_snackbar.dart.lib.js:38:61)
    at ApiChecker.checkApi (http://localhost:60787/packages/efood_multivendor/data/repository/auth_repo.dart.lib.js:38045:25)
    at splash_controller.SplashController.new.getConfigData (http://localhost:60787/packages/efood_multivendor/data/repository/auth_repo.dart.lib.js:38091:34)
    at getConfigData.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43063:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:42919:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:37493:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38088:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38126:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:37963:23)
    at http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38200:38
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:42924:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:37506:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38104:51)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38130:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:37963:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38015:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43223:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:43229:13)
    at http://localhost:60787/dart_sdk.js:38359:9
```

Comment: Hard to know for sure without the source code, but my best guess is that it fails at this line inside the `get` framework: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/6ab6adb731c503f75827c90677f90b0dd35d93da/lib/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart#L96 . So the problem is that `Get.overlayContext` returns `null` and we enforce that it is must not be `null` using `!` *(which inserts the runtime check that fails).  For why this field is `null`? I have no idea and this could maybe be more an issue for the issue tracker for `get`: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues

Comment: The `overlayContext` seems to be defined [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/9d2b87242aa5d5b54aebd4d635d1e16835635c49/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart#L1161), where it is dependent on the GetX controller's global key to provide the current state. My guess is that the way widgets are initialized in Web are different enough from Mobile that when your code calls this function for the first time, the current state hasn't been configured yet. Or maybe the overlay hasn't been created yet.